# RJAGS output Node inconsistent with parents

Tags: node.js, bayesian, mcmc, jags, r2jags

Hi everyone I'm new in JAGS and currently doing a bayesian inference using mcmc through RJAGS. I've been trying my best to debug my code until I'm stuck with this error "Error in node e1[3] Node inconsistent with parents".

```
e1<-c(1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1)
e2<-c(1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1)
c1<-c(2412,3485,881,1515,1824,1603,865,2638,332013,7379,1,1189,1,106,278,1406,9408,21596,15880,833,543,611,272,7883,
      1,15091,11642,849,203,566,425,1,125124,687196,21377,3901,1131,543,1,21218,1118,5519,434800,1288,4700,820,659,6644,
      1198,3581,1013,1021,5877,833,1,11797)
c2<-c(1189,905,902,1154,20896,14973,1665,1,1096,309,641,1,935,282,
      1,566,2245,112,18366,1096,1476,1,2486,1131,607,67,19390,284,
      641,566,1154,1,2672,4857,1131,1231,4594,655,1127,4187,1223,417,
      3381,1,1006,1,1920,4964,1911,765 ,876,14,942,849,4130)
n<-c(56,55)

model<-function() {
  #control
  for(i in 1:n[1]){
    e1[i] ~ dbern(p1[i])
    c1[i] ~ dlnorm(eta[1],lambda[1])
    p1[i] <- ilogit(alpha[1]+beta[1]*c1[i])
  }
  #treatment
  for(i in 1:n[2]){
    e2[i] ~ dbern(p2[i])
    c2[i] ~ dlnorm(eta[2],lambda[2])
    p2[i] <- ilogit(alpha[2]+beta[2]*c2[i])
  }

  for (t in 1:2) {
    eta[t] ~ dgamma(9,2)
    lambda[t] ~ dunif(0,100)
    alpha[t] ~ dnorm(0,1)
    beta[t] ~ ddexp(0, gamma)  
  }
 gamma ~ dunif(1,10)
}

library(R2jags)
dataJags <- list("n","c1","c2","e1","e2") 
params <- c("eta","lambda","alpha","beta")
inits <- function(){
  list(eta=runif(2,0,1),lambda=runif(2,0,1),alpha=runif(2,0,1),beta=runif(2,0,1)
  )
}
n.iter <- 10000
n.burnin <- 5000
n.thin <- floor((n.iter-n.burnin)/500)
flxpin <- jags(dataJags, inits, params, model.file=model,
               n.chains=3, n.iter, n.burnin, n.thin,
               DIC=TRUE, progress.bar="text")
```

I hope anyone can give me how to debug this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried invoking JAGS without explicit inits? Just leave out the inits argument in the jags() command. At least that way you'll know whether it's something to do with your initialization.

Comment: it did work :D Thanks a lot :D JohnK.Kruschke